# Converting timestamp in microseconds to data and time in r

Tags: r, timestamp, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

I'm trying to convert a timestamp in microseconds to the following format in R:

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

I've tried different approaches, but couldn't succeed. Following my code:

`options(digits=16)
value = 1521222492687300
as.POSIXct(value, tz = "UTC", origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")`

And I get this as return:

`[1] "48207591-10-13 12:15:00 UTC"`

Even divided by 1000, as some posts suggested, I'm still getting a non sense result:

`as.POSIXct(value/1000, tz = "UTC", origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
[1] "50175-08-15 19:31:27.300048 UTC"`

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: A microsecond is 1 millionth of a second, not one thousandth of a second.

Answer (score 3):

As Gabor hinted you need to divide by 1e6, not 1e3:

```
R> v <- 1521222492687300
R> v
[1] 1.52122e+15
R> anytime::anytime(v / 1e6)
[1] "2018-03-16 12:48:12.6872 CDT"
R>
```

Same of course with `as.POSIXct` etc but you nee to supply the redundant origin:

```
R> as.POSIXct(v / 1e6, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2018-03-16 12:48:12.6872 CDT"
R>
```

One way to see your scale is to convert current time:

```
R> w <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
R> c(v, w)
[1] 1.52122e+15 1.52346e+09
R>
```

which makes the scaling difference more obvious.

Comment: The *"see your scale"* is a great point, clearly showing the issue.

Comment: Also works in the same manner with `lubridate` if preferred over `anytime` by doing `lubridate::as_datetime(v/1e6)`.